# Does the jQuery attach/select process have any known race conditions that would prevent a selector from finding an element by id?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, race-condition

I create a modal dialog and run an ajax request to populate its contents.  The 'success' handler adds the content to the modal dialog via the jQuery `html` method, and then a 'complete' handler calls a callback and passes it a reference to the modal dialog.

In that handler, I create a selector for the content `$('#constant-id')`, but it sometimes fails, having a length of zero.  It usually does not fail if I put a debugger breakpoint before it and step through it.  On the other hand, if I put a breakpoint after it and look at the logged results, it has failed.  With the breakpoint after, if I inspect the reference to the modal that was passed to the method, I can see that the element is rooted in the body, and if I traverse its children, the `#constant-id` element is there.

So basically, after calling `element.html(content)` where element is a jQuery object that's already in the document, why would an element with `#constant-id` in the attached content not subsequently be found by a jQuery selector matching its id?

Comment: Strange. It looks like the issue may be because of a nested form in the loaded content (i.e. there's already a form around the entire page). I didn't expect the form element itself to be stripped out during the attachment via the call to jQuery.html.  So, there were multiple issues going on here; first my container selector was wrong, so the modal dailog wasn't initially attached at all.  After showing it, it automatically attached itself outside the form.  Now that it's attaching in the right spot, it fails consistently because of the form element being stripped out of the attached content.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't appear to be any kind of race condition; rather there was way too much black-box behavior going on between jQuery, 3rd party plugins, and a DOM that's too forgiving (i.e. silent failures... bad, bad, bad).

The first issue was that I was trying to attach a modal dialog inside a form (not intentionally, but that's where my container happened to be), but I had the wrong selector, so the dialog was not initially attached at all, let alone inside the form.  Meanwhile, that failure wasn't apparent, because the dialog still displayed, but it displayed only because it attached itself automatically to the document (outside the main form).  So it was failing the first time (since it was initially not attached when the handler ran), but succeeded on subsequent displays of the dialog, because it was already attached at that point (but not where I thought it was).

After correcting the attachment issue, it started failing consistently (consistency is good).  Upon inspecting the document, I saw that the content was attached to the modal dialog, but the form element that wrapped it was mysteriously gone.  I wasn't removing it, but when looking for the form element, it suddenly occurred to me that there was already an outer form element, which could be an issue.  So, it must be the case that when attaching a form to the document inside another form, the browser will actually strip the element out (a silent failure) while allowing the rest of the content to be attached.